# Storing Action<T> in a single collection for later usage

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to hold in memory a collection of references of type `Action<T>` where T is variable type

I've found a solution with `dynamic` but I would prefer not to use dynamic the solution

```
public class MessageSubscriptor:IMessageSubscriptorPool
{
    Dictionary<Type, Action<dynamic>> Callbacks = new Dictionary<Type, Action<dynamic>>();
    public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback) where T :IMessage
    {
        Callbacks.Add(typeof(T), (obj) => callback(obj));
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a better approach to handling this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Action<T>` is a `Delegate`, therefore...

```
public class MessageSubscriptor:IMessageSubscriptorPool
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _callbacks = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public void Subscribe<T>(Action<T> callback) where T :IMessage
    {
        _callbacks.Add(typeof(T), callback);
    }
}
```

Then, say you want to invoke one, you can simply perform a cast:

```
public void Invoke<T>(T message) where T :IMessage
{
    Delegate callback;
    if (_callbacks.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out callback))
        ((Action<T>)callback).Invoke(message);
}
```